# Sipios' Spring Boot JPA Search - Querying Enum

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, enums, spring-data-jpa

I am using **Spring Boot** (2.7.3) and **Sipios' library for Spring Search** for JPA Entities (https://github.com/sipios/spring-search).

I am trying make a search based on one of my class's enum fields, but receive the following error:
***InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Parameter value [FIRST] did not match expected type [*.MY_ENUM (n/a)];***

To make it clear through an **example**, let's say I have an entity-class "***MyClass***" which has a field "***MY_ENUM enumField***", and *MY_ENUM* has the values *('FIRST', 'SECOND', 'THIRD')*.
I am trying to query for all *MyClass* entries that have the value '*FIRST*' in their *enumField*.
The *enumField* is annotated with **@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)**.

For those familiar with the specific library, my HTTP request is: ***localhost:8080/controller/search?search=enumField:FIRST***.
I have also tried putting the *FIRST* query param in single & double quotes but the result was the same.

**I have traced the problem** to Hibernate's *org.hibernate.query.spi.QueryParameterBindingValidator*, method *isValidBindValue()*.
Method *isValidBindValue()* checks whether value "***FIRST***" is of ***MY_ENUM*** type.

More specifically, the line that effectively causes the exception is *expectedType.isInstance(value)*, where *expectedType* is "*class MY_ENUM*" and *value* is "*FIRST*", which evaluates to ***false*** and thus the error message - values checked via Intellij's debugger.

I have tried it with versions **0.2.3 & 0.2.4** of sipios/spring-search.
I saw that version 0.2.3 should support querying enums but I couldn't find any relative examples on how to do it, so it may be possible I have misunderstood how to use *spring-search*, but **I would expect Spring Boot to recognise the "*FIRST*" string as an instance of *MY_ENUM* type**.

Comment: `org.hibernate.query.spi.QueryParameterBindingValidator` is not part of spring, but of hibernate. And hibernate requires an `@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)` on the field

Comment: You are right, I mispoke by saying it's Spring's. Also, my enum field is already annotated with @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING), and I am debugging this in a freshly created database (mysql) so it is indeed a varchar column - Sorry I forgot to mention it!